# can not find image in subfolder in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I am building a very simple app for viewing pictures in a loop.
All pictures are stored in a subfolder in the project:
[image: project structure]

And this is the code in ViewController:

```
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        var images = [UIImage]()

        let items = Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "jpg", inDirectory: "images")
        for item in items {
            let fileName = URL(string: item)?.lastPathComponent ?? "c1.jpg"
            let image = UIImage(named: fileName)!
            images.append(image)
        }
        imageView.image = UIImage.animatedImage(with: images, duration: Double(5*items.count))
    }
}
```

This throws a runtime error on the line `let image = UIImage(named: fileName)!`

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value: file

The value of the fileName is "c1.jpg" which sounds right.

And if my memory is still working, the same code was working on the simulator but had the runtime error on real device, and now it stop working on both. Not sure what is wrong? I can see the "images" folder is listed in the "Build Phases" so I think the images should be copied to the bundle?: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
let image = UIImage(named:"images/\(fileName)")!
```

---

OR

```
 let items = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "jpg", subdirectory: "images") ?? []

  for item in items {

       if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf:item) {
           let image = UIImage(data:imageData)!
           images.append(image)
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this works! but I am very wondering why the subfolder name is required to make it work? I am new to the swfit/ios, what I learnt from some tutorial is the fileName is enough to get the image and this was actually working in my previous experiment. So I am not sure why it doesn't work in my case?

Comment: `UIImage(named:` reads from the root of the project directory so it doesn't recursively query the folder named `images` ,  note there is a difference between a blue and yellow folder color , your current case is blue which actually will create a folder inside the project bundle unlike the fake yellow one

Comment: you can also use `contentsOfDirectory` to read only names of images

Comment: okay I see it now! The folder which was working was in yellow! I made the mistake between blue and yellow folders!

Comment: BTW, there is some small glitch with the second solution: "inDirectory" is replaced with "subdirectory", and "image" should have a "!" or "??" in the end. The IDE throws these two errors.